# ggtern disables some themes from ggplot2 - still?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtern

I seem to have the same problem as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38442603/ggtern-disables-some-themes-from-ggplot2) earlier: when attaching ggtern to ggplot2 I receive this message:

The following objects are masked from ‘package:ggplot2’:

```
%+%, aes, annotate, calc_element, ggplot, ggplot_build, ggplot_gtable, ggplotGrob,
ggsave, layer_data, theme, theme_bw, theme_classic, theme_dark, theme_gray,
theme_light, theme_linedraw, theme_minimal, theme_void
```

The solution in 2016 was to update to version 2.1.4 of ggtern, however, I am now using version 3.1.0 for ggtern (and 3.3.0 for ggplot2). Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: It's just a conflicts message since `ggtern` likely "depends" on `ggplot2`. Check out the `conflicted` package.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you have a masked object, you can always point to that object with a qualified call (for example, using `ggplot2::theme_bw()`).

To see for yourself, load `library(ggplot2)` and `library(ggtern)` (in that order).  As you indicate, this function is masked in `ggplot2` as a result.  The changes are minor in the case I use below, but it illustrates the point.

Compare carefully the output of the following two lines of code and you can see the difference (I think mostly in the default size of the axis scales):

**Unqualified call.**  This code is using `theme_bw()` from `ggtern`, since `ggplot2::theme_bw()` is masked:

```
ggplot2(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width)) + 
    geom_point() + theme_bw()
```

**Qualified Call.**  This code calls the method from `ggplot2`:

```
ggplot2(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width)) + 
    geom_point() + ggplot2::theme_bw()
```